# Puma - No such file or directory - connect(2). No idea where it's getting this location from

Tags: ruby, nginx, sinatra, puma

So, I'm trying to deploy a Sinatra app with Capistrano. I have deployed the app successfully, however I am unable to start Puma. When I enter my app's `current` diretory and run `pumactl -F config/puma.rb start` I get the following error:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-195:/srv/apps/cx/current$ pumactl -F config/puma.rb start
[18512] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[18512] * Version 4.3.5 (ruby 2.5.1-p57), codename: Mysterious Traveller
[18512] * Min threads: 2, max threads: 6
[18512] * Environment: staging
[18512] * Process workers: 1
[18512] * Phased restart available
No such file or directory - connect(2) for /srv/apps/cx/releases/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock
```

I have no idea how or why it's looking in the cx/releases directory. I've attached some of my files below and maybe someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

Puma.rb

```
# Change to match your CPU core count
workers 1

# Min and Max threads per worker
threads 2, 6

app_dir = File.expand_path('../../..', __FILE__)
shared_dir = "#{app_dir}/shared"

# Default to production
rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'staging'
environment rails_env

# Set up socket location
bind "unix://#{shared_dir}/tmp/sockets/puma.sock"

# Logging
stdout_redirect "#{shared_dir}/logs/puma.stdout.log", "#{shared_dir}/logs/puma.stderr.log", true

daemonize

# Set master PID and state locations
pidfile "#{shared_dir}/pids/puma.pid"
state_path "#{shared_dir}/pids/puma.state"
activate_control_app

on_worker_boot do
  require 'active_record'
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect! rescue ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(YAML.load_file("#{app_dir}/current/config/database.yml")[rails_env])
end

lowlevel_error_handler do |ex, env|
  Raven.capture_exception(
    ex,
    message: ex.message,
    extra: { puma: env },
    transaction: 'Puma'
  )
  # note the below is just a Rack response
  [500, {}, ['An error has occurred, and engineers have been informed. Please reload the page']]
end
```

Puma.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Connect-Puma Server
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=ubuntu
# EnvironmentFile=/srv/apps/cx-api/current/.rbenv-vars
Environment=RAILS_ENV=staging
WorkingDirectory=/srv/apps/cx/current/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec puma -C /srv/apps/cx/current/config/puma.rb
ExecStop=/usr/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec pumactl -F /srv/apps/cx/current/config/puma.rb stop
ExecReload=/usr/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec pumactl -F /srv/apps/cx/current/config/puma.rb phased-restart
TimeoutSec=15
Restart=always
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

etc/nginx/sites-enabled/cx

```
pstream sinatra {
    server unix:/srv/apps/cx/shared/tmp/puma.sock;
}
server {
    root /srv/apps/cx/current/public;
    server_name staging.ldelivers.com;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/index.html @puma;
    }
    location @puma {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://sinatra;
  }
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/staging.lmdelivers.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/staging.lmdelivers.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = staging.lmdelivers.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    listen 80;
    server_name staging.lmdelivers.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

As you can see I'm not calling to the /releases directory anywhere. If anyone can get me pointed in the right direction I would appreciate it soo soo much.

Thanks

Comment: I am not familiar with this framework, but you define the socket path as `.../tmp/puma.sock` in one configuration file and `.../tmp/sockets/puma.sock` in another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
app_dir = File.expand_path('../../../..', __FILE__)
```

Also, the socket path is set as `.../tmp/puma.sock` in one configuration file and `.../tmp/sockets/puma.sock` in another.